# How to duplicate a table with constraints, indexes, etc. in APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table, which I would like to duplicate, but have different table name. I need data, indexes, constraints all to be duplicated. How can I do it solely within APEX?

Comment: Would the SQL queries work for you? If yes, then copy the the metadata of old table, replace the table name and execute the new queries from the metadata.

Comment: There is SQL workshop -> SQL commands, where I suppose it's possible to write queries. I can give it a try.

Comment: Looking at SQL metadata of table, I see there is associate trigger and sequence. I assume this would work, but is there better way, in case a table has more such dependencies?

Comment: Check my answer. You might have to tweak the way it needs to be executed, I don't have APEX to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Generate DDL file. Especially effective if required coping multiple tables

With in Apex go to SQL Workshop > Utilities > Generate DDL > create script

Select the schema.

Select objects required (table,trigger etc)

Next then select objects names (table name, trigger name etc)

Also see [Using Oracle Application Express Utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/user.32/e13370/sql_utl.htm#AEUTL256)

Answer (score 0):

Try this from SQL workshop. You might have to tweak the way it is executed, I don't have APEX to test it.

```
execute DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'PRETTY',TRUE);
execute DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'STORAGE',FALSE);
execute DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',false);

TRUNCATE TABLE PLAN_TABLE;

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM ;

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL (object_type, object_name, object_owner)
FROM   plan_table
WHERE  object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW');

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL ('INDEX', index_name, index_owner)
FROM   all_indexes
WHERE  table_owner, table_name IN (
    SELECT object_owner, object_name
    FROM   plan_table p
    WHERE  object_type IN ('TABLE')
);
```

**edit** In place of `<your table>`, put the table name.

Comment: in place of what? could you please bring example on how to use this? Would it take care of triggers and sequences associated with that table?

Comment: Oops, sorry, just edited. The code is for the parameters passed to get the metadata, like table, index etc.